# $f$ - isomorphism in a model category $\implies$ $f$ is fibration, cofibration and weak equivalence?

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

Why must an isomorphism in a model category be fibration, cofibration and weak equivalence simultaneously?

Thank you.

Comment: Identity is in each of them since these are subcategories, and every isomorphim is a retract of an identity morphism.

Comment: A very elegant solution, thank you. I have never thought that "every isomorphim is a retract of an identity morphism", however it is very easy to imagine a diagram that proves this.

Comment: @siddharth64 Who are subcategories?

Comment: fibrations, cofibrations and weak equivalences are

Comment: They are just classes of morphisms.

Comment: Some authors define them as classes (e.g. Dwyer), some - as subcategories (e.g. Hovey). I like the second approach better.

Comment: But then I suppose you add as part of the definition what actually follows from other axioms.

Comment: I don't think it's criminal. For example, the lemma you wrote in your answer suggests that if we were to try to make our definition of a model category contain minimal number of axioms and made up words, then we would have to choose only one class out of fibrations and cofibrations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\require{AMScd}$

Isomorphisms have liftings against everything.

It is known that a map $f: A \to B$ is a trivial cofibration iff it has extension property against all fibrations. Proof: factor $f$ as a trivial cofibration followed by a fibration: $A \to Z \to B.$ Then there is a lifting $B \to Z.$ It follows that $A \to B$ is a retract of a weak cofibration $A \to Z$.

$\begin{CD}
A @>{W.C.}>> Z \\
@V{\simeq}VV @V{F.}VV \\
B @>{=}>> B.
\end{CD}$

Likewise, trivial fibrations are precisely maps with the right lifting
property with respect to all fibrations.

Comment: I like @siddharth64's answer a bit more, but this certainly is correct and quite elegant too.